# PHP Postgres query using timestamp interval

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, timestamp

I'm trying to run a query using 2 timestamps.  I'm not sure how to add a day to the "to" timestamp. I would like to add a day, therefore 23:59 on 03-31 would be included. If there is a better way to do this inclusive search, feel free to let me know as well.

```
$from = "2014-01-01";
$to = "2014-03-31";

pg_prepare($db, 'my_query'
        , "select * from table where from >= $1 and to < $2 + interval '1' day");

$results = pg_execute($db,'my_query',array($from, $to));
```

Comment: `where foo between '2014-01-01' and '2014-03-31'` is about all you're need. `between` is inclusive, and can be re-written as `where foo >= '2014-01-01' AND foo <= '2014-03-31'`

Comment: Will this include times between `'2014-03-31 00:00:01' and '2014-03-31 23:59:59'`

Comment: `where foo:date`, if it's a datetime field? if all you're interested in is the date range, then ignore/suppress the time values.

Comment: '2014-03-31 23:59:59' isn't the last instant of 2014-03-31. PostgreSQL defaults to [microsecond precision in timestamps](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-datetime.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
pg_prepare($db, 'my_query', "
    select * 
    from table 
    where \"from\" >= $1 and to < $2::date + interval '1' day
");
```

Since `from` is a reserved word it must be double-quoted. Yes you need to add a day so the whole day of `03-31` is included.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `integer` to a `date` (which would not work on a `timestamp`):

```
pg_prepare($db, 'my_query', "
    select * 
    from table 
    where \"from\" >= $1 and \"to\" < $2::date + 1");
```

Plus, what @Clodoaldo wrote about [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html), and `to` is reserved as well.
It would be wise *not* to use reserved words as identifiers at all.